# Getting keys from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I've read through a couple of dozen of these questions, but I can't find this solution. I want to output the key of a JSON key:value pair. Assuming the JSON is like this:

```
{"group":[
{"ed":"BDeveloper","st":"New","type":"B"},
{"ed":"BDeveloper","st":"Cancelled","type":"B"}
]}
```

I want to scrape the "ed", the "st", etc. out of the pair using jQuery if possible.

I currently have code around it to output the data:

```
$.getJSON('sum.php', function(JSONsum)
        {
        var summaryHTML ='';
        $.each(JSONsum.group, function (i)
            {
            console.log("this.ed: ["+i+"] "+this.ed);
            // console.log("this.name: ["+i+"] "+this.something??? );

            summaryHTML+='<div class=\"grid_3\">'+this.ed+'</div>';
            summaryHTML+='<div class=\"grid_1\">'+this.type+'</div>';
            summaryHTML+='<div class=\"grid_2\">'+this.st+'</div>';
            summaryHTML+='<div class=\"clear\"></div>';
            });
        $('#summary').append(summaryHTML);
        });
```

But I want to be able to output the key in the console.log and use it in other places, etc.

Is it even possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you can access  the value with `this.ed`, then the key is `ed` and you can just use it as string...

Comment: right, but what if I didn't know that it was 'ed'? Or what if I wanted the HTML to build itself like: var objkey = something, then I could putput '<div class=\"grid_3\">+this.objkey+...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can look like following:

```
var jsonSum = {group:[
        {ed:"BDeveloper",st:"New",type:"B"},
        {ed:"BDeveloper",st:"Cancelled",type:"B"}
    ]},
    summaryHTML='',
    group=jsonSum.group;

for (var i=0, l=group.length; i<l; i++) {
    var obj=group[i];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (typeof console !== "undefined") {
                console.log("this." + prop + "["+i+"]: '" + obj[prop] + "'");
            }
            summaryHTML += '<div class=\"grid_' + prop + '\">'+obj[prop]+'</div>';
        }
    }
    summaryHTML += '<div class=\"clear\"></div>';
}
$('#summary').append(summaryHTML);
```

I replaced the class names `grid_1`, `grid_2`, `grid_3` to `grid_ed`, `grid_st`, `grid_type`. With the classes defined for example as

```
.grid_ed {float:left; background-color:red; width: 90px}
.grid_st {float:left; background-color:yellow; width: 90px; margin-left: 10px}
.grid_type {float:left; background-color:green; width: 90px; margin-left: 10px}
.clear {clear:left}
```

you will have the following results

[image]

and

[image]

in the log.

You can see this live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jQuery/JsonWithProperties.htm).

Comment: Very nice! For the record, the grid_# represents the classes for use with the 960.gs grid system. I will use Id to capture the 'prop' and combine in a serialize. Clever. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change the fourth line to: `$.each(JSONsum.group, function (i,e)`

`i` is the key/index and `e` is the value. Adding a `console.log(i+" : "+e);` should do it. Take a look at the [full documentation of each](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Here's my output.sigh. 
0 : [object Object]
1 : [object Object]
2 : [object Object]
3 : [object Object]

Comment: try `console.log(i + " : "); console.log(e);`

Comment: That gives 0 :
log: Object { ed="BDeveloper", more...}
1 :
Object { ed="BDeveloper", more...}
2 :
Object { ed="BDeveloper", more...}
3 :
log: Object { ed="BDeveloper", more...}

Comment: since `e` is another object, concatenating  it with a string made it `[object Object]` in the first example. But if you log the object separately, it will log the contents of it. Is this the output you were looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to carve out a string that I can use that is the key, like 'ed'. I'll work on getting the string out of the object.

Comment: You can do a `$.each(e,function(i_1,e_1){ // do sth with i_1 });` inside the each that is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery map function:

```
      keyArray = $.map(jsonarrayname, function(value, key){
        return key;
      });
```

This will result in an array containing the keys.